# Why can't I install Mysql on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I tried everything purge and install many times.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

output

```
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
2022-05-03T11:44:20.790604Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010946] [Server] Failed to start mysqld daemon. Check mysqld error log.
Warning: Unable to start the server.
Failed to preset unit: File mysql.service: Link has been severed
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on mysql.service: No such file or directory
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

I looked now at above mentioned logs

```
[ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
2022-05-03T11:36:53.787528Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
2022-05-03T11:36:53.788000Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2022-05-03T11:36:53.788246Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2022-05-03T11:36:53.789640Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
```

I am adding my /var/lib/mysql

```
var/lib/mysql# ls -la
total 119220
drwx------  5 mysql mysql     4096 мај  3 20:42  .
drwxr-xr-x 77 root  root      4096 мај  3 13:36  ..
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql    16384 мај  3 13:31  aria_log.00000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql       52 мај  3 13:31  aria_log_control
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql       56 мај  3 13:36  auto.cnf
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql        0 мај  3 13:36  binlog.index
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql        0 мај  3 13:58  debian-5.7.flag
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql   196608 мај  3 13:36 '#ib_16384_0.dblwr'
-rw-r-----  1 mysql mysql  8585216 мај  3 13:36 '#ib_16384_1.dblwr'
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql      976 мај  3 13:31  ib_buffer_pool
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 12582912 мај  3 13:31  ibdata1
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 мај  3 13:31  ib_logfile0
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 50331648 мај  3 13:05  ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 мај  3 13:05  mysql
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql       15 мај  3 13:05  mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 мај  3 13:05  performance_schema
drwx------  2 mysql mysql     4096 мај  3 13:05  test
```

How can I look further into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just some pointers:

Are you sure your storage isn't full? Note that MySQL/MariaDB stores its tables in /var/lib/mysql - which may be on a partition that's out of space.

Check permissions on the MySQL storage dirs.

Did you migrate tables manually in, via copy in the storage paths? If so, don't do this. MySQL on 20.04 has many changes from previous versions. Dump your data in the old version and make a fresh import.

Same question here, on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392329/failed-to-initialize-dd-storage-engine
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846631/mysql-8-wont-start-after-data-dictionary-upgrading-in-log-file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just added the whole content,take a look.

Comment: No problem with partition.